# Turning Inequality with $x$ into Inequality with $|x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

My textbook jumps from
$$-3<x-7<-1$$
to
$$|x-7| \ge 1$$
I don't understand how the second statement was derived from the first.

Comment: The first statement is equivalent to $|x-5|\lt1$

Comment: As robjohn commented, you seem to have a typo. It should be $|x-5|$. Note that, $$-3\lt x-7\lt -1\iff -1\lt x-5\lt 1\iff |x-5|\lt 1$$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas The textbook rewrote $|x-5|<1$ in the compound inequality form, before saying that it means $|x-7| \ge 1$. So, I assumed it would be easier to get to the final statement from the compound inequality and so wrote that as the first statement in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x-7$.

If $$-3 < y < -1$$

then we know that $y$ is negative for sure.

Also, by multiplying $-1$.

$$1 < -y < 3$$

Since $y$ is negative $-y = |y|$.

$$1 < |y| <3$$

which implies that $|y|\geq 1$.

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? Is there another way of thinking about it? Just because my textbook made it seem like it was a really obvious step.

Comment: It is actually kinda obvious, just look at the graph of $|x|$, if $-3<x<-1$, we can easily know that $1<|x|<3$.

Answer (score 0):

Because if $$-3<x-7<-1$$ then $$x-7<-1,$$ from which we get
$$x-7<-1$$ or
$$x-7>1,$$ which is
$$|x-7|>1.$$

Let $X$ be some inequality on $\mathbb R$ with one variable and $T(X)$ be the truth set of $X$.

We'll say that an inequality $A$ implies an inequality $B$

(we'll write this so: $A\Rightarrow B$)

iff $T(A)\subset T(B).$

In our case let $A$ be $-3<x-7<-1$ and $B$ be $|x-7|>1$.

Since $T(A)\subset T(B)$, we see that $A\Rightarrow B$.

Comment: The statement $-3 < x - 7 < -1$ is equivalent to $|x - 5| < 1$.  Also, you made an error.  If $x - 7 < -1$, then $-x + 7 > 1$, not $x - 7 > 1$.